# Service-based Database not listed in VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

New to the forum, hoping for some help.  I have just started getting into Visual Studio and have installed VS Community 2015.  I have searched for this answer and though it is listed a few times, the things that I saw in those threads I tried but no luck and it says not to ask questions, only provide a suggested answer so that's why I have started this new one.  I am using this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx to create a sql database.

On the third line of instruction, it says: In the list of item templates, scroll down and choose Service-based Database.  However, under Visual C# items, Service-based Database is not listed.  I followed instructions in another thread to delete and re-setup the templates but it still does not show.  I also confirmed that I have SQL Server Data Tools installed as SQL Server Object Explorer is listed when I go to the VIEW menu.

In the templates area when creating a new project, there is a SQL Server section below the Visual C# area which is for creating a new database project.  It does not show it as Service-based Database so is it just a newer version of it and I should try my luck with that?  I'm at a loss otherwise.

Thanks,

Todd

Comment: Did you try `If it's not there, go to Add Remove Programs, click on Visual Studio 2015, choose Change, and check the box next to SQL Server Data Tools`?

Comment: Hi Barry, I did mention that in my thread that I confirmed that it is installed, thanks.